# My C program to find closest pair of numbers from user input is not printing the right output?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, math

I am trying to find the closest pair of numbers entered by the user. My C code isn't working right and I can't figure out what's wrong. I think it might have something to do with storing the values but I don't know where to go from here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j,arr[50], first,second;

    //loop input
    for(i=0;i<50;i++) //loop 50 times
    {
        scanf("%d", &i); //scan
        //break if i=-1      
        if (i==-1)
            break;
        //if not print    
    }
    //2nd num - 1st num < 3rd num-1st num, closest = 1st and 2nd num
    //i[0]=num1, j[0+i]=2nd num, i= 4 , 5, 7, ans=arr,
    //if j[0+i]-i[0]= ans < j[0+i]-i[i]=ans 
    //arr[i]=8,2,17,4,25
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<50;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]-arr[i]<arr[j+1]-arr[i])
            {
                first = arr[i];//3
                second = arr[j+1];//5
            }
        }   
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", first, second);

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: `if(arr[j]-arr[i]<arr[j+1]-arr[i])` needs review.  I'd expect something more like `abs(arr[j]-arr[i]) < abs(first - second)` after an initial pair is found.

Comment: @chux I fixed my code but I still have a question. I put it on the comment below.

Comment: Post input used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't post it as answer, prefer editing your code instead. Anyway, the problem is here :

```
for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++)//j<i <-why is it wrong?
```

How isn't it wrong? You've initialised `j` with the value `i+1`. How's it supposed to be ever less than `i`? And due to that, it's picking up values from outside the array and providing you with unexpected results.

The correct form is :

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this chunk of code. You're scanning in the counter variable `i` instead of array. And then you're manipulating stuff using array `arr`. Why should that work in any scenario?

```
 for(i=0;i<50;i++) //loop 50 times
        {
            scanf("%d", &i); //scan
            //break if i=-1      
            if (i==-1)
                break;
            //if not print    
        }
```

And `i` can never be `-1` unless it's a miracle.

Comment: I fixed my code but I still have a question. I put my question on the comment below.